# having trouble psr-4 autoloading in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

Okay so I have an project folder inside my Laravel app. named TLGD (the name if my site). Inside i created a form validation helper which is being used to take away unnecessary code form the controller.

here is the folder structure:

```
TGLD\Validation\Forms
```

and inside here I have my form helper classes

now in the controller just to test it out I was calling the classes by the use methd from php like so:

```
use TGLD\Validation\Forms\Login;
```

login being the class for the login validation

now thus works great so I tried to autoload the TGLD folder so I don't need to add the use line in every controller. Here is my composer.json file

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "TGLD\\": "app/TGLD"
    }
},
```

but when I autoload it it gives me the error that my login class doesn't exist which means the autoloader is not working. Is there a syntax error or am I missing something? I ran

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

well any advice is helpful thank you in advance

Comment: autoloading != `use`. You still need to use the `use` statement. What you could do is setting up an alias for your Form Validator, but I wouldn't do that.

Comment: no other way to make it so I don't need to require the use for all y controllers?

Comment: It's all about namespaces http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php, so basically no. You can setup an alias for your Laravel app in `app/config/app.php` but like I said, I wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do cannot be done.

You have to use the complete namespace somewhere to identify the class you want to use. You have several options to do this

1. Using the fully qualified name of the class with namespace like this: `new \TGLD\Validation\Forms\Login()`.
2. Using a `use` clause that imports the named class into the current namespace for this file with `use TGLD\Validation\Forms\Login; ... new Login();`
3. Using a part of the namespace in the `use`, and use the rest in the class name: `use TGLD\Validation\Forms; ... new Forms\Login();`

After you have chosen the class name in one way or the other, PHP knows which class it needs, and then triggers the autoloading if the class is still unknown to PHP.

So you cannot affect the naming of classes with autoloading.